# How to add parameters to Websocket requests in JMeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter

1. How to add the below details to the WebSocket Open connection? (please check the links below)
2. Is my understanding right - The details in the above Screenshots are to be added to WebSocket Open connection. Following which I can have WebSocket request-response Sampler using the same connection.

Answer (score 1):

1. - Some headers like `Sec-WebSocket-Key` and `Upgrade` are being added by the [Java
     code](https://github.com/Luminis-Arnhem/jmeter-websocket-samplers/blob/c112c06c856b0cd682e54e8adc480e864babdcd1/src/main/java/eu/luminis/websocket/WebSocketClient.java#L189), you can take a look at WebSocketClient.java file to see which and how. For the others - WebSocket Samplers respect [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)
   - With regards to request parameters - just add them to the "Path" section

   [image]
2. For the headers - they will be added as per [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), for the Path - if you decide to use existing connection - it will be propagated